# Moving the cursor in relation to a certain fix-point in Python

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

is there any possibility to move the cursor in Python with % starting from a certain coordinate like (1,1)?
I am using pyautogui atm to automate and I thought it would be quite convenient if this is independent from the monitor size making it universal.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible indirectly. As detailed at the top of the [Mouse Control Functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html) page of the documentation, you can get the screen size using the `size()` function (which returns a tuple of `(X, Y)`). You can then do the math to figure out how many screen pixels equal the percentage you're looking for, then call `moveTo()` to go there.

```
# script to move mouse 50% to the right and down
import pyautogui as pag

percentage = 0.5
cur_X, cur_Y = pag.position() # current X and Y coordinates
size_X, size_Y = pag.size() # screen size
goto_X = (size_X - cur_X) * percentage + cur_X # current location plus half
goto_Y = (size_Y - cur_Y) * percentage + cur_Y # the distance to the edge

pag.moveTo(goto_X, goto_Y, 1) # move to new position, taking 1 second
```

Comment: first of all, thank you! so there is no possibility to write e.g. something like pyautogui.moveTo(2%, 30%)? Even not when using something else than pyautogui?

Comment: Edit: actually tried to use percentages, does not work of course but I would like to see if there are any alternatives. From a CSS basic course I know that it's possible there

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use percentages in some situations, like CSS, but if this library isn't written to accept them directly, then you'll just need to calculate them yourself, which will only be an extra line or two of code. There's nothing inherent to Python that wouldn't allow you to use them in other circumstances, it's just that you can't using pyAutoGUI, as all its movements are done using pixels.

Comment: okay I understand, thank you. I just thought when it's possible to use percentages it would allow to apply the script on several screens with different sizes. last question: is there any other possibility in python in general to do so?

Comment: pyAutoGUI is really the most well-developed GUI automation library for Python, and is the one I'm most familiar with. There may be others, but I don't know about them. If you give me a minute, I'll post some example code on how to move by percentages.

Comment: OK, please see my added code example